# Where to put identification data of Android application?

Tags: android

I'm making library which requires user identification data, let's say applicationID. Where should I make developer put it's identification data? I wouldn't like to make them to set it runtime, because I would like their code to be as clean as it can be while using library. Where should I make them put it? What is the best practise? I couldn't find any document relevant to this topic. I know that Facebook Android SDK suggests putting app_id into string.xml, but that's somewhat dirty in my opinion.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always like to use meta data. For example [**SugarORM**](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html) uses this. With it you can define things in the manifest like this:

```
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:name="com.orm.SugarApp">

    <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db" />
    <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
    <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example" />

</application>
```

In most cases this would be best practice. Reading the meta data is quite simple:

```
ApplicationInfo ai = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle metaData = ai.metaData;

if(metaData.containsKey("DATABASE")) {
    String dbName = metaData.getString("DATABASE");
    ...
}

if(metaData.containsKey("VERSION")) {
    int dbVersion = metaData.getInt("VERSION");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest solution. Thanks!

Comment: I added an example on how to read meta data from the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of options ;

**1.Sqlite**

**2.SharedPreferences**

**3.Asset folder**

in asset folder you can use xml or your data type.